# Displaying List of AutoHotkey Hotkeys

Tags: autohotkey, tabular, hotkeys

I’ve written script that contains numerous hotkeys (general structure is as below). I would like to create another one that when pressed displays a list of all of the hotkeys and their corresponding descriptions that the script contains in a nice, formatted table.

The formatting and display are tenuous since AutoHotkey’s output is limited to message-boxes, but possible. More problematic is getting the hotkeys and corresponding descriptions.

The hotkeys all call the same function with different arguments. I considered adding a variable to the function so that depending on the value, the function either performs the normal function when triggered by the normal hotkeys, or builds a string or something when triggered from the special display hotkey.

I cannot figure out a way to programmatically access the script’s hotkeys at all. I checked the docs and there don’t seem to be any `A_` variables that can be used for this purpose, nor does the `Hotkey` command lend itself well (it can be used to test if a hotkey exists, but looping through the innumerable combinations is, *at best*, tedious).

Failed attempts:

- I tried using Elliot’s suggestion of parsing the script itself (replacing the path with %A_ScriptFullPath%, and while it does work for a raw script, it does not when the script is compiled
- I tried assigning the entire hotkey section of the script to a variable as a continuation section and then parsing the variable and creating hotkeys using the `Hotkey` command. This worked well right up until the last part because the [`Hotkey`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851677/) command cannot take arbitrary commands as the destination and requires *existing* labels.
- The `ListHotkeys` command is not applicable because it only displays the hotkeys as plain text in the control window.

Does anyone know how I can display a list of the hotkeys and either their corresponding arguments or comments?

---

Example script:

```
SomeFunc(foobar)
{
  MsgBox %foobar%
}

         !^#A::SomeFunc("a") ; blah
 ^+NumpadMult::SomeFunc("c") ; blivet
        ^+!#`::SomeFunc("b") ; baz
      ^#Space::SomeFunc("d") ; ermahgerd
 …
```

Example desired “outputs”:

```
C+A+  W+ A   a    | C+ S+   NumpadMult  b
------------------+----------------------
C+A+S+W+ `   c    | C+   W+ Space       d
```

or

```
Ctrl Alt Shift Win  Key         Action
-----------------------------------------
 ×    ×         ×   A           blah
 ×        ×         NumpadMult  baz
 ×    ×   ×     ×   `           blivet
 ×              ×   Space       ermahgerd

etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It is not perfect (or ideal), and hopefully a proper, built-in method will become available in the future, but it works well (enough) and for raw and compiled scripts.

What I did was to use the [`FileInstall`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileInstall.htm) command which tells the compiler to add a file to the executable (and extract it when run).

Sadly, the `FileInstall` command will not allow the use of variables for the source file, so I cannot simply include the script itself (`FileInstall, %A_ScriptFullPath%, %A_Temp%\%A_ScriptName%, 1`).

As a work-around, I ended up extracting all of the desired hotkeys to a second file which I then parse as Elliot suggested, then delete, and `#Include` at the end of my script (it *must* be at the end since hotkeys will terminate the [autoexecute](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm) section).

```
;;;;; Test.ahk ;;;;;

; Add hotkey file to executable and extract to Temp directory at runtime
FileInstall, Hotkeys.ahk, %A_Temp%\Hotkeys.ahk, 1

Loop
{
  ;Read a line from the extracted hotkey script and quit if error
  FileReadLine, line, %A_Temp%\Hotkeys.ahk, %A_Index%
    if ErrorLevel
      break

  ;Trim whitespace
  line=%line%

  ; Parse the line as in Elliot’s answer, but with tweaks as necessary
  ParseHotkey(line)
  …
}

FileDelete, %A_Temp%\Hotkeys.ahk ; Delete the extracted script
DisplayHotkeys()                 ; I ended up bulding and using a GUI instead
#Include, Hotkeys.ahk            ; It is included at compile-time, so no A_Temp



;;;;; Hotkeys.ahk ;;;;;

z::MsgBox foo
y::MsgBox bar
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is to read each line of your script individually and parse it.  This code reads your script (script.ahk) one line at a time and parses it. This should get you started. Additionally, you could parse the line to check for the modifiers as well.

```
Loop
{
    FileReadLine, line, C:\script.ahk, %A_Index%
    if ErrorLevel
        break

    If Instr(line, "::")
    {
        StringSplit, linearray, line, ::,

        key := linearray1
        StringSplit, commandarray, linearray3, `;

        action := commandarray2

        hotkeyline := "key:  " . key . "`tAction:  " . action
        final .= hotkeyline . "`r"

    }
}
msgbox % final

return
```

Comment: Ouch! That is certainly not ideal. Interesting idea though, and I suppose it could work for a simple script (like this one) and would only have to be done once. I’ll check to see if there’s a way to access the filename instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the path, `A_ScriptFullPath` can be used. I parsed the modifiers to show `CASW` instead of `^!+#`, and trimmed the whitespace. I’m currently working on formatting it better (unfortunately the messagebox is limited in width and uses a proportional font which means either misaligned text or one hotkey per row). I’ll probably just end up building a GUI to display the hotkeys, but the above method works well for parsing them, especially since it only has to be done once on startup (at least until they add a built-in method to access them in an array or something). Cheers.

Comment: Uh oh! Big problem. This method does not work if the script is compiled. `:-(`