# Dynamically Create AutoHotkey Hotkey to Function/Subroutine

Tags: function, dynamic, hotkeys, autohotkey, subroutine

The AutoHotkey command `Hotkey` allows for the creation of dynamic hotkeys at runtime, but its syntax and documentation seems to limit it to built-in or existing labels/subroutines, which makes it *much* less useful:

> Hotkey, KeyName [, Label, Options]

Is there a way to get it to work like regular, hard-coded hotkeys? For example:

```
#z::MsgBox foobar        ; Typical, hard-coded hotkey pops up a message-box

Hotkey, z, MsgBox foobar ; Nope; complains about missing label “MsgBox foobar”
```

It looks like it might be possible due to the following line from the manual, however it is not clear how it would work:

> Label - Both normal labels and hotkey/hotstring labels can be used.

Comment: Apparently, I'm not getting it. Could you give more detail about what you are looking for?

Comment: The example above is exactly what I am looking for; a way to do the following without having to manually create a labeled subroutine for each and every hotkey dynamically created: `Hotkey, z, MsgBox foobar`

Comment: It's not possible to do exactly how you describe.  Can you give a realistic example of what you want to do?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand, in the script that brought this issue up, I have ~200 hotkeys that call a function (which has optional arguments), passing it different parameters. I **can’t** create separate labels/subroutiens for each and every one, and even if I could, I *don’t want to* because it would make it difficult to add or remove hotkeys instead of just modifying a single line. I *may* be able to work around this with the current script by using arrays and `A_ThisHotkey`, but even if that works, it doesn’t really address the issue of dynamic hotkeys to functions (or what dynamic labels are).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doing exactly what you want isn't possible in AutoHotkey.  This is the closest way I can think  of.

Call this file `Hotkeys.ahk`, and put it in `My Documents/AutoHotkey/Lib`.  Alternatively make a folder called Lib, and put it in the same directory as your main script.

```
Hotkeys := {}

Hotkey(hk, fun, p*) {
    global hotkeys
    hotkeys[hk] := {}
    hotkeys[hk].fun := fun
    hotkeys[hk].p := p
    Hotkey, %hk%, HandleHotkey
}

HandleHotkey:
hotkeys[A_ThisHotkey].fun(hotkeys[A_ThisHotkey].p*)
return
```

Here's an example script that you could use it with.

```
Hotkey("e", "msgbox", "foobar")

MsgBox(msg) {
    msgbox % msg
}

#Include <Hotkeys>
```

The first parameter is the hotkey, the second is the function to call, and everything after that is passed to the function.

Comment: Yup, this is what I was [thinking of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851677/dynamically-create-autohotkey-hotkey-to-function-subroutine/12875053#comment17422315_12851677); creating a generic handler. It doesn’t fix the `Hotkey` command’s limitation, but it’s a satisfactory solution. I like that your example provides the ability to supply different arguments so that other functions can be called. One note though, the `Include` has to be moved to the end of the script because it terminates the auto-execute section, so the calls to the `Hotkey` function are never done if it’s at the start.

Comment: A couple of notes. **(1)** I had to remove the asterisk from the function definition in order to get it to work (`Hotkey(hk, fun, p*)` ⇨ `Hotkey(hk, fun, p`) **(2)** For some reason using `E` as the key to the associative array does not work (`A`, `B`… `Z`, `^E`, `+E`, etc. all work). It looks like a bug with AHK’s array handling (or maybe it’s a special key, but not as far as I can find; only `base` seems to be special).

Comment: The asterisk lets you pass any number of parameters, if you remove it, you can only pass one (not a big deal if that's all you need).  You could still pass an array if you like, though.

Comment: Also, try using lowercase hotkeys.  `e` means the 'e' key, `E` means Shift-e.  `e` works for me.

Comment: `e means the 'e' key, E`   Nope; `+e` and `+E` mean *Shift+E*, both `e` and `E` mean *E*. `e` doesn’t work either; for some reason it seems to be invalid as a key. (I’m using _L 1.1.7.1 and _L 1.0.48.5 doesn’t support `{}` and replacing it with `Object()` did nothing at all.)

Comment: An old answer, but I just started with AHK and this just saved me so many ugly lines of code. Thank you! :)

Comment: Because the `hotkeys` is like a `Map`; \
if you have **duplicate hotkey**  in different `#IfWinActive` (& use them as the key of the Map); \
the `latter hotkey` will **overwrite** the `prev hotkey`.

Answer (score 10):

This is a refinement of FakeRainBrigand's answer. It is used exactly the same:

```
Hotkey("x", "Foo", "Bar") ; this defines:  x:: Foo("Bar")
```

Changes from the original:

1. **Prevent accidental auto-execute** of the handler subroutine by tucking it into the function.
2. Allowing me to **reduce namespace pollution** by narrowing the scope of the `hotkeys` variable from global to static.
3. **Optimizations**: `fun` is looked up only once (using `Func()`) at hotkey definition time; At invocation time, object lookups reduced four to two by splitting `hotkeys` into two objects `funs` and `args`;

This still relies of course on the _L version of AutoHotKey because of Object notation and variadic `arg*` syntax.

```
Hotkey(hk, fun, arg*) {
    Static funs := {}, args := {}
    funs[hk] := Func(fun), args[hk] := arg
    Hotkey, %hk%, Hotkey_Handle
    Return
Hotkey_Handle:
    funs[A_ThisHotkey].(args[A_ThisHotkey]*)
    Return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook

Hotkey, #z, MyLabel

MyLabel:
    MsgBox,OK
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

With newer ahk version you can now use functions as label argument. See https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm

Answer (score 0):

In `Hotkey, KeyName, Label, Options`; You can use a `Function Object` instead of a `label`.

#### ex

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force 
#Persistent

func_R := Func("print").bind("RRRRRRR")
func_P := Func("print").bind("PPPPPPP")

Hotkey, % "^r", % func_R ; <<<
Hotkey, % "^p", % func_P

print(output) {
  ToolTip, % output
}


; ;@note; Dont know why you cannot do the following::
; ;@note;
; ;@note; Hotkey, % "^r", % Func("print").bind("RRRRRRR")
; ;@note; Error:  Nonexistent hotkey. -- ^r
```

Press `^r`, the corresponding function will be executed.

#### ref

> ~// [] 
> ~// [Hotkey - Syntax & Usage | AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Hotkey.htm) 
> ~// Creates, modifies, enables, or disables a hotkey while the script is running. 
>
> [] 
> [[v1.1.20+]:](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/AHKL_ChangeLog.htm#v1.1.20.00) If not a valid label name, this parameter can be the name of a function, or a single variable reference containing a function object. For example, `Hotkey #z, %FuncObj%, On` or `Hotkey #z, % FuncObj, On`. 
>
> https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Hotkey.htm 
>
> ~// [] 
> ~// Function Hotkeys [v1.1.20+] 
> ~// One or more hotkeys can be assigned a function by simply defining it immediately after the hotkey label as in this example: 
> ~//  
> ~// https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotkeys.htm#Function \